# How to make webview become firstresponder after alerview dismissed

Tags: ios, webview, first-responder

I have a viewcontroller A which contains a webview, A is on the top of a navigation view controller.The webview is used to load a web page,the web page contains a text field and a button.

If I click the button, an UIAlertView shows in APP. After I click 'OK' button(in the UIAlertView) to dismiss the alert view, I want to type into the text field, but I can't, because the text field can't become editable. I click on it and it has no response. At this time, I can only click the back button of the navigation controller.

I've tried to use:

```
[webView becomeFirstResponder];
```

this doesn't work.

If I use:

```
[webView reload];
```

It works.But I don't want to use reload, because it needs time.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
-(void)setUpWebView{
    NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@“url"];
    NSURL* nsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30];
        [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}


-(void)showWebView{
    [self setUpWebView];
    self.viewThisWebView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0 , 320, 560);
    self.viewThisWebView.alpha = 0;
    [self.view addSubview:  self.viewThisWebView];
   
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        self.viewThisWebView.alpha = 1;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        
    }];

}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
        
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
          [self showWebView];
            
        }

    }
```